# Flex + Spring + BlazeDS + Glassfish + OpenMQ - How do you configure the web-application-config for OpenMQ?

Tags: apache-flex, spring, message-queue, blazeds, spring-integration

I have the spring-flex-testdrive example (JMS chat application which uses a Topic to pub/sub messages) to work on Tomcat with ActiveMQ now I want to run this example on Glassfish with OpenMQ.

This is a related sample config I found online but it doesn't quite work for the Flex/Glassfish/OpenMQ/BlazeDs/Spring-Integration technology combination. 
 ([Link](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:eUBFAc2QMoYJ:blog.nominet.org.uk/tech/2007/09/04/high-availability-jms-with-open-message-queue-and-spring/+spring+JmsTemplate+openmq+OR+%22open+MQ%22+-activeMq+-%22active+mq%22&cd=17&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us))

I can deploy it on Glassfish but it can't connect to the destination. I've seen forums mention just replace ActiveMQ with OpenMQ classes/bean declarations but that does not appear to be the case. How do you configure the web-application-context.xml for OpenMQ? What are the common gotcha's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="CustomOpenMqConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="imqAddressList" value="localhost:7676" />
    <property name="imqDefaultUsername" value="admin" />
    <property name="imqDefaultPassword" value="admin" />
</bean>

<bean id="chatTopic" class="com.sun.messaging.Topic">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="cTopic"/>
</bean>
```